# How to add cmis extensions to each property separately

Tags: cmis, opencmis

I am adding extensions to a property using below code snippet.

```
Properties props = objData.getProperties();
        Map<String, PropertyData<?>> properties = props.getProperties();

        for (String prop : properties.keySet()) {
            PropertyData propData = properties.get(prop);
            propData.setExtensions(extensions);
        }
```

But at the client end, I am not reveiving these extensions.

```
Property prop = cmisObj.getProperty("cmis:name");
List<CmisExtensionElement> extensions  = prop.getExtensions();
```

I am getting null, whenever I called the getExtensions() method on a property. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any other way to add extensions to a cmis property while sending response from server?

Comment: Hi Hari...can you try this List<CmisExtensionElement> extensions = cmisObject.getExtensions(ExtensionLevel.PROPERTIES); check here https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/extensions/index.html

Comment: Hi Saurav, Thank you for the reply. The solution suggested by you will work to get property level extensions. But I would like to add extenstions to each property separately at server end and read the extensions associated with each property at client end.